# C free all selected memory in a single free() call

Tags: c, linux, memory

I am working with a C function `freeMemory()` that gets as input a series of pointers and frees the memory occupied by those as follows:

```
void freeMemory(char **parallel_commands, struct command *comands[], size_t num_parallel_commands) {
  free(parallel_commands);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_parallel_commands; i++) {
    for (struct command *cmd = comands[i]; cmd->num_argumentos != 0; cmd++)
      cleanCommand(cmd);
    free(comands[i]);
  }
}
```

You can assume `cleanCommand()` function has a free inside it (equivalent to a `free()` call). Since there are nested loops in the function and each iteration free has to call the operating system to free the required memory, this process becomes inefficient.

Is there any way to parallelize the freeing of the memory inside `freeMemory()` function? Or is there any way to free all the selected memory in a single call (knowing all the pointers to the corresponding memory sections)?

Comment: Do not tag C questions as C++.

Comment: "*is there any way to free all the selected memory in a single call*" - not if the memory wasn't all allocated with a single `malloc` call to begin with. The fact that you have to make multiple `free` calls implies that is not the case.

Comment: `free(comandos_paralelos)` looks like a leak if this is a pointer to, presumably, other pointers. Who owns those allocations?

Comment: @remy-lebeau Although there are allocated in several calls, is there any operation that performs the free operation in parallel for multiple memory sections?

Comment: You may want to create a single `struct` you can allocate and release.

Comment: `free`ing memory can get tricky and bug-prone just like any other code.. perhaps ask yourself if [you really need to free it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584062/should-i-free-memory-before-exit)

Comment: @remy-lebeau *commands[] is a 2D array with variable number of elements per entry, that's the reason for the nested loop as it is.

Comment: You must match every `malloc()` with `free()` making sure of the reverse order where the structures are nested. If it's a bit complex, set the pointer to `NULL` after you `free` it, then you can't double-free the same pointer (unless you made copies of the pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to parallelize the freeing of the memory inside freeMemory() function?

You could start multiple threads to do the freeing, but you would likely find this counterproductive, making the overall procedure more costly.

> Or is there any way to free all the selected memory in a single call (knowing all the pointers to the corresponding memory sections)?

No. Each `malloc()`ated region that is to be `free()`d requires its own call to `free()`.

Unless you count `exit()` -- on a hosted implementation, you can reasonably expect the OS to reclaim all of a process's resources when that process terminates.  Some authorities specifically recommend *not* going to any effort to free remaining allocated memory when the program exits.  [Example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120105-00/?p=8683).

---

But if you find that freeing many independent allocations is causing problems for you, then you could consider aggregating them into fewer allocations (that is, allocate fewer, larger regions in the first place).  Even if that means you consume more memory overall, it might well be worth it.